# "ext.flutter.driver" is not found in "extensionRPCs" - What would be the issue?

Tags: flutter, appium, flutter-test

When I start running the appium flutter script, I get this error and wait for 5 minutes. After that it continues the execution.

```
[FlutterDriver] Attempt #1
[FlutterDriver] Connecting to Dart Observatory: ws://127.0.0.1:39420/uVLSKORHloI=/ws
[FlutterDriver] Connected to ws://127.0.0.1:39420/uVLSKORHloI=/ws
[FlutterDriver] "ext.flutter.driver" is not found in "extensionRPCs" ["ext.ui.window.scheduleFrame"]
[FlutterDriver] Cannot get Dart Isolate
[FlutterDriver] Error: "ext.flutter.driver" is not found in "extensionRPCs" ["ext.ui.window.scheduleFrame"]
[FlutterDriver]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:74:35)
[FlutterDriver]     at Client.onOpenListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/lib/sessions/observatory.ts:91:17)
[FlutterDriver]     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
[FlutterDriver]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[FlutterDriver] Waiting 300 seconds before trying...
(node:71547) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: "ext.flutter.driver" is not found in "extensionRPCs" ["ext.ui.window.scheduleFrame"]
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:74:35)
    at Client.onOpenListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/lib/sessions/observatory.ts:91:17)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:71547) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Whaat would be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

So basically flutter app needs to have instrumentation enabled for the test automation to take effect.
Hence you need to add  enableFlutterDriverExtension(); in main.dart while creating the debug app.

Just add that before runApp()

Comment: I don't think that works, even after adding it has the same problem